# clojure: var defined inside function is breaking precondition

Tags: clojure, var, preconditions

I have this function:

```
 (defn executa-peso-individuo 
   [estado-individuo transicao-individuo]
   (def tipos-transicoes-peso #{:troca-peso :mesmo-peso})
   (def tipos-estados-peso #{:d :e})
   {:pre [(contains? tipos-transicoes-peso
                     (:peso transicao-individuo))
          (contains? tipos-estados-peso
                     (:peso estado-individuo))]
   ...
```

Preconditions are not working. Somehow the vars tipos-transicoes-pes and tipos-estados-peso are creating a bug in the precondition code.
I know I can put those vars outside my function to make it work. But I would like to keep those definitions inside my function. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you defining vars inside functions? It's not considered a good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the pre- and post-conditions map to be recognized as such, it must immediately follow the parameter vector. See http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc10.

An acceptable albeit not very common way to package these would be to wrap your `defn` in a `let`

```
 (let [tipos-transicoes-peso #{:troca-peso :mesmo-peso}
       tipos-estados-peso #{:d :e}]
   (defn executa-peso-individuo 
     [estado-individuo transicao-individuo]
     {:pre [(contains? tipos-transicoes-peso
                       (:peso transicao-individuo))
            (contains? tipos-estados-peso
                       (:peso estado-individuo))]
     ...
```

In general, reserve `def` and `defn` for top-level use only. Inside a top-level `let` is okay, but again, not common. But, definitely do not use inside a function body as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the condition. They should go after function's param vector.

```
(defn fun [param-1 param2]
{:pre  [ ]
 :post [ ]}
 ;; body goes here
)
```